# Idea 14 and 15 is sometimes irritatingly slow in editor. How to fast?

Tags: performance, intellij-idea

I found that IntelliJ Idea sometimes is becaming irritatingly slow.

Sometimes it is not VERY slow, but sometimes it is slow like bad web page. The impression that is think and waits on each keystroke or each word.

Much slower than Visual Studio.

The speed was one of the main reason I switched from Eclipse. I would not like if IntelliJ will turn to the same as Eclipse but for money.

Are there any means to speed up an IntelliJ?

I have added

```
editor.zero.latency.typing=true
```

into `idea.properties` but had no effect.

**UPDATE**

Already set

[image]

but this didn't help.

**UPDATE 2**

I found that slowness depends on what is written in code. I.e. it is somehow related with automatic code inspection or something.

I don't want to disable inspection completely, but just don't want it runs each keystroke. Is it possible to increase delays somewhere?

Comment: Have you seen the Performance Tuning page at JetBrains? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/tuning-intellij-idea.html You might need to increase your VM size, as a first guess. IDEA runs fast for me (on OS X).

Comment: Even if you wanted, the inspection cannot even be disabled. You can disable the presentation of the inspection results, but the CPU waisted for checking cannot really be saved

Answer (score 1):

Please report your problems in [Jetbrans's youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues). Usually you need to provide your CPU Usage profile. How to enable it you can read here: [Reporting performance problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64-bit machine, you can launch IntelliJ IDEA from `idea64.exe`, not `idea.exe`

Second thing, as the comment suggests, you can edit your `idea64.exe.vmoptions` (that's spelled correct, `.vmoptions` is the file extension, while `.exe` is part of the filename) in `pathToIntelliJ/bin` by increasing values in lines starting from `-Xms` and `-Xmx` (that is: memory for JVM while starting and maximum amount of memory). You may not be able to edit this file in place, but you can copy this file to another location (where you have permission to edit it), edit this file and copy it back to `/bin` folder.